# Access Control and policy conflict resolution methods

Tags: security, access-control, policy

Just to re phrase my question:

I am actually working on policy combination and conflicts resolution for distributed networks. As distributed open systems, digital resources can be protected by a
collection of security policies created by different entities which have a different copy 
of the resource.

After searching in the web, I used key words such as "Access Control policies", "security policy conflict resolution", but I didn't find many results or even a survey of all different methods

Some approaches to combine policies & resolve conflicts that I found included: "Negative policies prevails", "assign priorities to policies" e.t.c. but not a way to combine or encompass them.

Are there any different current directions to apply AC policies or is just a question of choice between classic policies such those mentioned above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question belongs on security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at research done in the space of policy-based access control. Look at papers on:

- policy-based access control
- attribute-based access control
- OASIS [XACML](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml) which implements policy-based access control and policy combining algorithms.

Academics in this field include:

- Elisa Bertino from Purdue ([DBLP](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/b/Bertino%3aElisa))
- Theo Dimitrakos from BT/Kent([DBLP](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/d/Dimitrakos%3aTheo))
- Ludwig Seitz from SICS ([DBLP](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/s/Seitz%3aLudwig))

NIST have also done some extensive research in this space which you can find on their dedicated websites:

- [Role-based access control](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SNS/rbac/)
- [Attribute-based access control](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/index.html)

Comment: Ok thnx for the info, I ll start search towards this direction!